# How to prevent a UILabel cutting off with '...'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I was wondering if there is any way to prevent an UILabel from cutting off with '...'? I have a CGRect which is 55 in width and 20 in height and I would like it to simply cut off after 55 (or clip the contents off) without indicating with '...' that there is more.

```
        UILabel *btnTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 55, 20)];
    btnTitle.text = labelMe;
    btnTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    btnTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    btnTitle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( ( 90 * M_PI ) / 180 );
```

I achieved what I wanted (i.e. the clipping) by putting the UILabel (with increased width, i.e. 100 x 20) into an UIView (55 x 20) and set clipsToBounds to YES with the result that I couldn't click my buttons anymore - because I was using the label to label a button. The UIView containing the label was hiding my buttons...

Is there a way around this without using an UIView to clip the contents of my UILabel?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this out:

```
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;
```

For more information, refer [UILabel Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilabel)

Hope this helps

Comment: Wonderful! Very easy indeed. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use `UILineBreakModeClip` or one of the other options. Set it with the `UILabel lineBreakMode` property.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell your view that contains your label to ignore touches and send them to the next available responder to do this just add this method to your view.m file

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Or even better, just set `userInteractionEnabled = NO` on the view.

Answer (score 1):

Swift4 version of Ole Begemann/eddyce's answer:

```
label.linebreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byClipping
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 version of **Ole Begemann's** answer:

```
label.lineBreakMode = .byClipping
```